# Returning Int value from Oracle DB using C#

Tags: c#, database, oracle

I am trying to return `INTEGER` value from Oracle Database using C# but it is giving me following Exception

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred
>   in System.Data.dll
>
> Additional information: Specified cast is not valid.

Can anyone help me to resolve this?

Here is my code:

```
OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(
  "Provider=MSDAORA;Data Source=xe;User ID=hr; password=123");
   con.Open();

String cmd1 = 
  @"select retail_price,purchase_price from 
    productdetails where item_name='" + textBox1.Text + "'";

OleDbCommand a1 = new OleDbCommand(cmd1, con);
OleDbDataReader myReader = a1.ExecuteReader();

if (myReader.Read())
{
    int m = myReader.GetInt32(0);
    MessageBox.Show("" +m);
}
```

Comment: try `int m = Convert.ToInt32(myReader[0]);` istead of `int m = myReader.GetInt32(0);`

Comment: You may wish to read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14376473/what-are-good-ways-to-prevent-sql-injection .

Comment: Microsoft `MSDAORA` provider is outdated for ages. Use the Oracle provider `OraOLEDB.Oracle`

Comment: @mjwills  i am unable to get what are you trying to tell. can you please explain that.?

Comment: I'd suggest having a read of https://github.com/tmenier/AsyncPoco or https://github.com/schotime/NPoco .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, according to the query

```
    select retail_price,
           purchase_price
      from productdetails 
     where item_name = :item_name
```

the actual type of `retail_price` as well as `purchase_price` can be some *floating point value* type (`double` or `decimal`; say, `8.95$ == 8.95`):

```
   decimal retail_price = Convert.ToDecimal(myReader[0]);
   decimal purchase_price = Convert.ToDecimal(myReader[1]);
```

If you insist on integers, *round* them up (`8.95$ == 8.95 -> 9`); assuming prices are *non-negative*:

```
   int retail_price = (int) (Convert.ToDouble(myReader[0]) + 0.5);
   int purchase_price = (int) (Convert.ToDouble(myReader[1]) + 0.5);
```

Answer (score 1):

Happening for a couple of reasons.

First, your price fields are likely to be decimal.   Next, you probably need to be more explicit when accessing fields on your reader.

Try:-

```
int purchasePriceint = Convert.ToInt32(myReader["purchase_price"]);
int retailPriceint = Convert.ToInt32(myReader["retail_price"]);
```